# How to permanently enable query cache in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to know if there's a way to permanently set the size of my query cache and to make sure it's always enabled. 
Right now, I'm just using the `set global query_cache_size` command to set the size, but when the database is restarted it goes away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set this parameter in `/etc/my.cnf` on Red Hat or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on Debian (other systems have the `my.cnf` file in various locations):

```
# vi /etc/my.cnf
```

Append config directives as follows:

```
query_cache_size = 268435456
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 1048576
```

Change the values as appropriate to your system!

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit MySQL configuration file and change these parameters accourdingly

`query_cache_size - 1-2 MB`

`query_cache_limit - 1-2 MB`

`query_prealloc_size` - Should be more than default if you have complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding the directives Max Vernon provided a few lines after the other directives under [mysqld] in my.cnf (or my.ini if on XAMPP) as opposed to adding the lines to the end of the configuration file or after [mysqldump] or [mysql].